# NS3 Custom Node and Packet Header

Tags: c++, simulation, ns-3

In NS3, is it possible to create custom network Nodes and packet header? I need to implement some new nodes for my simulation (new kind of switches, SDN Controller, cloud controller, etc.) and also modify the network packet header to include some additional information. I am new to NS3 but I am familiar with C++.

As for how to customize the network packet, I don't have any idea at all, and I am confuse where to start. But for creating custom nodes, I have read the tutorial book that all node are essentially derived from `Node` class (correct me if I'm wrong), so initially I imagined that I can just create my `CustomNode` class inheriting NS3's `Node` class like:

```
class CustomNode : Node { ... }
```

However, when I looked at the sample code, they provide many examples using `NodeContainer` helper used like:

```
NodeContainer container;
container.Create (1);
```

As we can see in the code, there is only one argument in the function `create()` which is related to the total number of nodes to be created and no other argument nor template to specify the type of the Node. I wish I could do something like:

```
container.Create<CustomNode>(1);
```

or something like that. Could anyone please give me some hints in how to achieve my goals?

Comment: you can also use `ns3::NodeContainer::Add(Ptr< Node > node)` to put your overloaded nodes into container and use `ns3::DynamicCast` to cast afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Sir, your suggestion is exactly what I'm looking for. How about customizing the network packet, is it possible to do in NS3?

Comment: You can do what ever you want, ns-3 is opensource. You also have to take a look at [ns-3 users google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ns-3-users), it's much more active than ns-3 tag on SO